# Insert few objects from an array in nsmutable dictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am having an array of 30 Images i want to add only 15 images to nsmutable dictionary and which are to be added randomly

I am using the following code

```
for (m = 0; m < 20; m++)
{   
 rnd = arc4random_uniform(FrontsCards.count);       

 dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];     
 [dic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rnd] forKey:@"Images"]; 
 NSLog(@"%@",dic);

}
```

here the problem is as for m=0 entry gets in dictionary ,for m=1 again an entry goes in dictionary replacing first one and at the end i get only the last value the desired output is all the 20 values can anybody help me out..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: `dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];` use outside the loop.

Comment: It's totally wrong ... 1st - you're allocating dictionary inside loop every time (= replacing the old one) as already mentioned. 2nd - you'll end up with one object in dictionary, because you still do use one key = @"Images". Your NSNumber object will be replaced. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You are actually allocating a `NSDictionary` 20 times with only single key `Images` and using none.

Comment: you are allocating nsmutabledict 20 times so you just add it the last key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the SAME TAG "**Images**" for every number you set. Hence it gets replaced again and again

```
 dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];     


for (m = 0; m < 20; m++)
{   
    rnd = arc4random_uniform(FrontsCards.count);       

    [dic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rnd] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images_%d",rnd]; 


}

 NSLog(@"%@",[dic description]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found many problem in your code:
1. You want to add 15 images but make loop of 20;
2. You are creating Dictionary in side loop so it will created 20 time. Each time new Dictionary is created and old one get deleted.
3. You ar using same key to store all value. You have to use unique key for each item. Other wise old itel get replaced

Use Like this

```
dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; 

for (m = 0; m < 15; m++)
{   
     rnd = arc4random_uniform(FrontsCards.count);       

     [dic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rnd] forKey:[NSString  stringWithFormat@"Image%d",rnd]]; 
}
NSLog(@"%@",dic);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating new dic evrytime. So it gets overwritten. Try this. Also as mayur said you cant use same key.

```
dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; 
for (m = 0; m < 20; m++)
{   
 rnd = arc4random_uniform(FrontsCards.count);       


 [dic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rnd] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images_%d",rnd]]; 


}
 NSLog(@"%@",dic);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enter more than one object or image with the same key... Here the key is set as Images. So the value for the key named images will be set again and again... Either you have to specify different name for key in each case or use an array to store all images.

Also declare the dictionary outside the for loop. Try the below code.

```
dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];   
for (m = 0; m < 20; m++)
{   
 rnd = arc4random_uniform(FrontsCards.count);       
 [dic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rnd] forKey:@"Images_%d", m]; 
 NSLog(@"%@",dic);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to use NSMutableArray because you are using again and again same key so last value will be replace by new value. So there are 2 option

1) First use different Key for every image.

2) You can use NSMutableArry to add new object.

Answer (score 0):

Above Answer is Right You follow this code and solve your problem.